# Função recursiva que simula um numero elevado a uma potência

Tags: python, algoritmo, recursão

Como simular a elevação dum numero a uma potência usando a **recursão** (e Python)?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sabendo que tenho que usar a **recursão**, a primeira coisa a encontrar é o caso base. Neste caso, o **caso base** é:

a<sup>0</sup> = 1

como provavelmente já sabem das lições de matemática. Onde *a* é a base.

### Qual é afinal o passo recursivo?

Das lições de matemática, sabemos que:

a<sup>n + 1</sup> = a<sup>n</sup> * a

ou seja a nossa base ***a*** elevada a potência de *n + 1* é igual a mesma base ***a***  elevada a *n*, vezes a nossa base ***a*** (só traduzi em palavras).

#### E como resolvemos **a<sup>n</sup>**?

Exato, aqui chega o ponto crucial, onde aplicamos a definição de *recursão*:

a<sup>n</sup> = a<sup>n - 1</sup> * a

E assim por adiante, aplicando sucessivamente a *recursão* a:

a<sup>n - 1</sup>

que penso já intuíram como resolver.

Traduzindo em Python (neste caso):

```
def power_r(base, power, show_steps=True):
    """show_steps serve só para dizer 
    se amostrar os passos recursivos escritos ou não."""
    if power == 0: # caso base
        if show_steps:
            print(base, "^{0} = 1", sep="")        
        return 1
    else: # passo recursivo
        if show_steps:
            print(base, "^{", power, "} = ", base, " * ", base, "^{", power - 1, "}", sep="")
        return base * power_r(base, power - 1, show_steps)
```

Tentando agora aplicar essa função:

```
print(power_r(4, 3))
```

usando como base *4* e como potência *3*, o resultado é:

```
4^{3} = 4 * 4^{2}
4^{2} = 4 * 4^{1}
4^{1} = 4 * 4^{0}
4^{0} = 1
64
```