# Soma sequência recursiva

Tags: python-3.x, recursão

Estou implementando um código recursivo que soma a seguinte sequência: x + x^2 / 2 + x^3 / 3... x^n / n, pra essa soma, pensei numa definição, combinando duas funções recursivas, como segue a baixo, porém ele está retornando valores muito altos, para n > 3.

```
def potencia(x, n):
    if n == 0: return 1
    else:
        return x * potencia(x, n - 1)

def Soma_Seq (x, n): 
    if n == 0: return 0
    else: 
        return x + Soma_Seq(potencia(x, n - 1), n - 1) / n
```

Answer (score 1):

Dado: `Soma(x,n) = x + x^2 / 2 + x^3 / 3 + ... + x^n / n`

Repare que:

```
Soma(x,n) = x + x^2 / 2 + x^3 / 3 + ... + x^n / n
#          |----------------------------|
Soma(x,n) =       Soma(x,n-1)           + x^n / n
```

Definindo que, para `n=1`: `Soma(x, 1) = x`

```
def potencia(x, n):
    return (x**n)

def Soma_Seq (x, n): 
    if n == 1: return x
    else: 
        return Soma_Seq(x, n-1) + potencia(x, n)/n
```

Podemos também escrever a função `potencia()` recursivamente da seguinte forma:

```
def potencia(x, n):
    if n == 1: return x
    else:
        return x * potencia(x, n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Podemos utilizar essa resposta para a sua pergunta:

[Função recursiva que simula um numero elevado a uma potência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46012/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-recursiva-que-simula-um-numero-elevado-a-uma-pot%C3%AAncia)

```
def potencia(base, power, show_steps=True):
    """show_steps serve só para dizer 
    se amostrar os passos recursivos escritos ou não."""
    if power == 0: # caso base
        if show_steps:
            print(base, "^{0} = 1", sep="")        
        return 1
    else: # passo recursivo
        if show_steps:
            print(base, "^{", power, "} = ", base, " * ", base, "^{", power - 1, "}", sep="")
        return base * potencia(base, power - 1, show_steps)

def Soma_Seq (x, n): 
    if n == 0: return 0
    else: 
        return x + Soma_Seq(potencia(x, n - 1), n - 1) / n
```

Acredito que é um bom ponto de partida.